# Is a point within a polygon

Tags: geometry, latitude-longitude, spherical-geometry

I need help in this [question](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15609). To explain briefly -- the question is:

Whether a point with coordinates

```
lng:-80.087535
lat: 42.054246
```

lies over or under line with coordinates:

```
lng: -80.267831 ... -73.362579
lat: 42.050312
```

If it lays under (as Thomas said) then could you please show me where I've made a mistake in my coordinate system vision?

[image: coordinate system]

**Update:**
Sorry, my mind after hours of thinking is not working now. I haven't explained base of the question.
I've got two rectangles: the big one(R1) and a small one(R2). R2 is a part of a R1. Also I've got a point(P1) which is seems to be in R2, as MongoDB query says, and is missing in R1 when querying (as was explained in question - because of earth curvature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers on this question:

- Point is lying under the line if the line is Geodesic (which means the shortest)
- Point is lying over the line if the line is "on axis" line

[image: explanation]

Taking in consideration that in MongoDB (2dsphere) polygons is completed using [geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesic) - point is in R2 and missing in R1.